# How does where and first_or_create work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

From this code I am having an SQL check and if provider and uid attributes are not found in any register then a new one is create. All fine with that. 
But when a new register is created it turns up to have the values checked for provider and uid. How is that happening? Shouldn't that code only create instances of user with the email, password and name attribute values? 
What is making the SQL insert provider and uid?

```
def self.from_omniauth(hash)
    where(provider: hash.provider, uid: hash.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = hash.info.email
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.username = hash.info.name
end
```

The Logs

```
User Load (25.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = $1 AND "users"."uid" = $2  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "879615942106023"]]
   (10.0ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (12.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'vinibol12@yahoo.com.br' LIMIT 1
  SQL (12.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("provider", "uid", "email", "encrypted_password", "username", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7) RETURNING "id"  [["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "879615942106023"], ["email", "vinibol12@yahoo.com.br"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$z3oK6H1P5Z0It7VliVw1hehF.Mn1kFlvZbru919lDR.IiHb94Ha/u"], ["username", "Vinicius Antonio Bolzani"], ["created_at", "2015-07-20 08:58:04.227271"], ["updated_at", "2015-07-20 08:58:04.227271"]]
   (2.4ms)  COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[first_or_create](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) creates new record if none found in DB, and when creating it uses those params you used for search, that is why you get `provider` and `uid` set-up as well. If you have not pass any block, you would get new record in DB with `provider` and `uid` only set-up.

Comment: That's the explanation I needed which I didn't find in the docs. Thanks. Choosing your answer in 4.

Answer (score 1):

first_or_create works this way that it will first search the database for the attributes in where clause. if found it will not create new, if fails it will create new one. Now even for new user, the query does not know that the given uid and provider exists or not so it has to run the query first to make sure. see this http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create. 'tries to load the record first if fails then create.'